# Getting the message statement & function not covered for findindex() & some branch is not covered as selectedgroup[0].desc

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting the message statement & function not covered for findIndex() & some branch is not covered as selectedGroup[0].desc. Please guide me how to I write test case in this below code statement function & branch covered.

```
updateCampaignGroup = async (id) => {
        let newArr = {
          id: parseInt(id),
          campaignGroupName:
            inputState.nameSelectedVal === ''
              ? selectedGroup[0].campaignGroupName
              : inputState.nameSelectedVal,
    
          campaignNumber: selectedCampaigns,
          goal:
            inputState.goalSelectedVal === ''
              ? selectedGroup[0].goal
              : inputState.goalSelectedVal,
          kpi:
            inputState.kpiSelectedVal === ''
              ? selectedGroup[0].kpi
              : inputState.kpiSelectedVal,
          desc:
            inputState.desSelectedVal === ''
              ? selectedGroup[0].desc
              : inputState.desSelectedVal,
          dailySpend: selectedCampaigns.length === 0 ? 0 : 450,
          createdAt: await new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb', {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'short',
            day: 'numeric',
          }),
          createdBy: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('okta-token-storage')).idToken
            .claims.name,
          dailySpendofTotal: selectedCampaigns.length === 0 ? 0 : 12,
           
        };
      
        const index = campaignGroupListing.findIndex((item) => item.id === parseInt(id));
        campaignGroupListing.splice(index, 1);
        campaignGroupListing.splice(index, 0, newArr);
        
        localStorage.setItem(
          'campaignGroupData',
          JSON.stringify(campaignGroupListing),
        );
        await setIsOpen(false);
        updateGroupListData(campaignGroupListing);
        toast({
          duration: 2000,
          position: 'top-right',
          status: 'success',
          title: 'Campaign group has been created successfully',
        });
        setInputState({
          nameSelectedVal: '',
          desSelectedVal: '',
          goalSelectedVal: '',
          kpiSelectedVal: '',
        });
      };
    
      const saveCampaignGroup = async () => {
        campaignGroupData.push({
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
          campaignGroupName: inputState.nameSelectedVal,
          campaignNumber: selectedCampaigns,
          desc: inputState.desSelectedVal,
          createdAt: await new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb', {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'short',
            day: 'numeric',
          }),
          createdBy: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('okta-token-storage')).idToken
            .claims.name,
          goal: inputState.goalSelectedVal,
          kpi: inputState.kpiSelectedVal,
          dailySpend: selectedCampaigns.length === 0 ? '-' : 450,
          dailySpendofTotal: selectedCampaigns.length === 0 ? '-' : 12,
        });
        localStorage.setItem(
          'campaignGroupData',
          JSON.stringify(campaignGroupData),
        );
        await setIsOpen(false);
        updateGroupListData(campaignGroupData);
    
        toast({
          duration: 2000,
          position: 'top-right',
          status: 'success',
          title: 'Campaign group has been created successfully',
        });
        setInputState({
          nameSelectedVal: '',
          desSelectedVal: '',
          goalSelectedVal: '',
          kpiSelectedVal: '',
        });
      };
```

[i am sharing test coverage live screen in which you can see statment & branch is not covered for findIndex & ternary condition data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u5in.png)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: basically how to i write test case for   this condition who covered findIndex & ternary operator 
& whole code that covered all branches ,statement & functions
    campaignGroupListing.findIndex((item) => item.id === parseInt(id));
                    campaignGroupListing.splice(index, 1);
                    campaignGroupListing.splice(index, 0, newArr);

Comment: Hi ceving Please help me for in unit test case

Comment: I do not understand your problem.

Comment: HI ceving only i ask ho why to i write test case for these code campaignGroupListing its is arrray of object inn this code i find matching data and updated id record append in a new array ."campaignGroupListing.findIndex((item) => item.id === parseInt(id)); campaignGroupListing.splice(index, 1); campaignGroupListing.splice(index, 0, newArr); "